# How to get an Element by Id in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I would like to get an outer [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) in Vue, using [`getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById):

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#vue",
  data: {
    helloElement: document.getElementById('hello')
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.2/vue.js"></script>
<div id="hello">
  hello
</div>
<div id="vue">
  {{helloElement}}
</div>
```

This brings me an empty `Element`, but not a `null` - which suggests that the query was partially successful (something was found).

This is actually a POC for a more general problem I face: the ability to get an outer `Element` (say, a container `div`) from within a Vue component (this brings me a `null`, which [the documentation says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById#Return_Value) to be the response when the element was not found).

**Is it possible, from within a Vue object or component, to query an outside `Element` present in the DOM?**

Comment: You code works. The real question what do you expect to see with `{{helloElement}}`?

Comment: @dfsq: this is a good question. I expected to see a structure, but I just tested and checked for a propriety (via `{{helloElement.scrollWidth}}`) and see that it does exist. Thanks - I should have checked that earlier. If you do not mind to turn your comment into an answer I would gladly accept it.

Comment: May I know, what exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: @Saurabh: I have a Vue component filled with text, it is on a page together with other components (fixed size). The text in the component will be variable, possibly so big that it would overflow from the screen (the application is a non-interactive one, a kind of dashboard which must fit in one window). Each time the text will change, I will change the size of the font, right up to an overflow (and then a bit back). I will check the overflow via `element.scrollHeight > element.clientHeight || element.scrollWidth > element.clientWidth`, where `element` is the outermost container.

Comment: @Saurabh (cont'd): This is why I needed the ability to get information about the container, which will be outside of the component which will implement the dynamic resize above.

Comment: Unless I'm completely misunderstanding the question, it sounds like you might be better off using refs: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a snippet accomplishing what I believe you want to do.  I modified your example to use classes since I wanted to avoid having two elements with the same id.
I'm just using `outerHTML` to get the DOM element as a string and then rendering it using Vue's `v-html`.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#vue",
  data: {
    helloElement: document.getElementsByClassName('hello')[0].outerHTML
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.2/vue.js"></script>
<div class="hello">
  hello
</div>
<div id="vue">
  <div v-html="helloElement"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

It is possible, as you can see. But be warned, that if you want something like this, your app is probably bad designed and you created entry poin for XSS attack.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#vue",
  data: {
    helloElement: document.getElementById('hello').outerHTML
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="hello">
  hello
</div>
<div id="vue" v-html="helloElement"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#vue",
  data: {
    helloElement: document.getElementById('hello')
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.2/vue.js"></script>
<div id="hello">
  hello
</div>
<div id="vue">
  {{helloElement.innerHTML}}
</div>
```

I think your code is working now and you are getting dom in helloElement.

[image: result]

Adding .innerHTML you will get the solution.