# using vuejs how do i get the value of content in a div and display inside of the model

Tags: vue.js

I am using vuejs and I want to get the value of a div and display it inside of the model. Issue is i Cannot use the recommended refs because I in reality cant modify the html. Does anyone have a basic solution where I can leverage vuejs and push the content to the model where location is?

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
   location:''
  },
  methods: {
        test:function(){
        if (!this.$refs.myRef) {
          console.log("This doesn't exist yet!");
        }
        }

  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
<div id="FilePathPlaceholder" class="d2l-placeholder d2l-placeholder-live" aria-live="assertive">
    <div class="d2l_1_234_979">
        <div class="d2l_1_235_849 d2l_1_236_43 d2l-inline">
            <span class="d2l-textblock"></span>
            <span 
                class="d2l-textblock d2l_1_237_505 d2l_1_238_137"
                id="d2l_1_233_684"
                title="/content/Stuff/12183-CC-242/">
                /content/Stuff/
                <strong>12183-CC-242</strong>/
            </span>
            <input type="hidden" name="FilePath" id="FilePath" value="/content/Stuff/12183-CC-242/">
        </div>
        <div class="d2l_1_237_505 d2l-inline">
            <span class="d2l-validator" id="d2l_1_239_562"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Before you can use `$refs`, you need to put the `ref` attribute on the element/component. Also I think you can use `v-model` to bind the input value on to location

Comment: Can’t use ref is what I’m saying above. Need an alternative.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get an Element by Id in Vue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47038283/how-to-get-an-element-by-id-in-vue)

Comment: What's the reason ref can't be used? Using ref is the recommended solution for this scenario in Vue.